# Trying to write a generic Makefile, I get Implicit rule search has not been done

Tags: makefile

Hi I am trying to write a generic (basic) Makefile to compile basic, practice c programs.
I have a src directory that I am practicing c programming in. My directory structure looks something like this:

```
practice/src/ex1.c
             ex2.c
             ex3.c
practice/build
```

my Makefile looks like this:

```
blddir = ./build
srcdir = ./src

# RM="find $(blddir) -maxdepth 1 -executable -type f -name 'ex*' -delete"

CFLAGS=-Wall -g

$(csrc): %.c
   $(CC) -o $(blddir)/$@  $(srcdir)/$^ # all prereqs

clean:
   find $(blddir) -maxdepth 1 -executable -type f -name 'ex*' -delete
```

When I run: `make ex6`, I am greeted with : `make: *** No rule to make target 'ex6'.  Stop.`
When I run: `make -p ex6 | less`
...and search for `ex6` I see:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL := src/ex6.c

src/ex6.c: %.c
#  Implicit rule search has not been done.
#  Modification time never checked.
#  File has not been updated.
#  recipe to execute (from 'Makefile', line 15):
    $(CC) -o $(blddir)/$@  $(srcdir)/$^ # all prereqs
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

...more reading more testing, new(er) Makefile:

```
blddir = ./build
srcdir = ./src

CFLAGS=-Wall -g

% : $(srcdir)/%.c
   $(CC) -o $(blddir)/$@  $^ # all prereqs
```

make ex6
...and it works

Comment: Please check Makefile: it does not include definition for csrc